# outer join works fine in sql server but not in the ms access linked to it

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, join

I've a query that has an outer join and used to work fine in access before, now I linked the tables to sql server and it return odbc failed, columns can't be bound error message, if I tried to run the query directly in sql server it works fine, if I make it as pass-through query in access, it runs fine!

```
SELECT a.*, b.P_Date, a.Tag_id
FROM (
       SELECT TP_Items.Tag_No, TP_Items.Tag_id, TP_Items.empty_wt, TP_Items.empty_wt*perc/100 AS perc_wt, TP_Prog_Act_Perc.Act_Descr, TP_Prog_Act_Perc.Perc, TP_Prog_Act_Perc.act_id 
       FROM TP_Items, TP_Prog_Act_Perc 
       WHERE TP_Items.Cont_ID=TP_Prog_Act_Perc.Cont_id 
          AND TP_Items.Proj_ID=TP_Prog_Act_Perc.Proj_id
     )  AS a 
LEFT JOIN 
     tp_prog_tag AS b 
     ON (a.act_id=b.activity_id) AND (a.tag_id=b.tag_id)
```

Comment: plz share more detals..

Comment: What happens when you run in Access `SELECT * FROM TP_Items`?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should read this. You are mixing join styles and using one that has been out of favor for over 20 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Thanks folks, appreciate your quick reply, I made some changes due to your replies but it still not working, here is the new one               SELECT a.Tag_no
            ,a.perc
FROM (
    SELECT tp_i.Tag_No
        ,tp_i.Tag_id
        ,tp_i.empty_wt
        ,tp_pap.Act_Descr
        ,tp_pap.Perc
        ,tp_pap.act_id
    FROM dbo_TP_Items as tp_i
    INNER JOIN dbo_TP_Prog_Act_Perc as tp_pap
    ON tp_i.Cont_ID = tp_pap.Cont_id
        AND tp_i.Proj_ID = tp_pap.Proj_id
    ) AS a
LEFT JOIN dbo_tp_prog_tag AS b 
    ON a.act_id = b.activity_id
    AND a.tag_id = b.tag_id

Comment: it works fine for the first part od the query, once I add the left join it returns ODBC Failed, the multi-part identifier "tp-i.Tag_id" could not be bound (#4104) for this field and for other linking fields Proj_id, Cont_id, (Tag_id once again!), any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi folks, have to work around and make both linking fields as one field in both queries, I know it costs as performance wouldn't be the best, but at least it works :)